# Current cell value in R

Tags: r

Using `ifelse()` statement if the condition does not hold I want to see the current cell value.

My attempt:

```
aghh.mrg1$whynoloan <- ifelse( is.na(aghh.mrg1$whynoloan) & (aghh.mrg1$haveloan==0 & aghh.mrg1$ifoloan==0 ),1, CURRENT.CELL.VALUE)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `CURRENT.CELL.VALUE`? Please provide a reproducible example of your problem, with a copy paste friendly sample dataset.

Comment: whynoloan is not an empty column so if the condition does not hold, I want to see the original value in that cell

Comment: Do you need `aghh.mrg1$whynoloan <- ifelse(is.na(aghh.mrg1$whynoloan) & (aghh.mrg1$haveloan == 0 & aghh.mrg1$ifoloan==0 ),1, aghh.mrg1$whynoloan)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Probably `replace` will be better here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (which is hard due to absence of information), you can do something like this:

```
aghh.mrg1$whynoloan <- replace(aghh.mrg1$whynoloan, (is.na(aghh.mrg1$whynoloan) & (aghh.mrg1$haveloan == 0 & aghh.mrg1$ifoloan == 0)), 1)
```

Comment: I dont wanna make it 1. I want to make it like aghh.mrg1$whynoloan[, that current cell ]..  in excel or vba it is call active.cell where you can do "offset " base on that active cell. it is like if your cursor is on cell N2 the below cell N3 and so on,